# Scala deserialize class dynamically using Gson

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, gson, deserialization

I am working in scala programming language

I want to deserialize json to a case class dynamically. So my v1 code is

```
  protected def DeSerializeJson(json: String): MyClass= {    
    val gson = new Gson
    val response = gson.fromJson(json, classOf[MyClass])
    response
  }
```

The above code only de-serializes json to MyClass. I want to make it reusable for other class as well with an extra argument of class type. so that I can pass different json and different type and it will return that particular class object. But I am not able to figure out the variable type of second parameter and how to call it. Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you have three case classes

```
case class MyClass(id:String)
case class MyClass2(name : String)
case class MyClass3(age : String)
```

Now, you can write the custom function with an additional parameter T denoting the class type as

```
protected def DeSerializeJson[T](json: String,classType: T) = {
  val gson = new Gson

  classType match {
    case MyClass =>  gson.fromJson(json, classOf[MyClass])
    case MyClass2 => gson.fromJson(json, classOf[MyClass2])
    case MyClass3 => gson.fromJson(json, classOf[MyClass3])
  }
}
```

Now based on the class type that we passed as an argument in the method, we can pattern match on it to get the required result.

By invoking the function with different parameters as

```
DeSerializeJson("{ \"id\" : \"101\"}",MyClass)
DeSerializeJson("{ \"name\" : \"Tom\"}",MyClass2)
DeSerializeJson("{ \"age\" : \"12\"}",MyClass3)
```

we get an output

```
res0: Product with Serializable = MyClass(101)
res1: Product with Serializable = MyClass2(Tom)
res2: Product with Serializable = MyClass3(12)
```